# DynamoDB one-to-many

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have read that DynamoDB can use sortkey to add items to a specific primary key. Coming from a world of SQL, I have a hard time understanding this concept.

Let's say we have the following: A user with a profile, many items and many family members.

Should I create just ONE table with e.g. a user id, and different sortkeys for the relevant information?
Like:

```
pk: userId, sk: ITEMS#{id:1, type: bottle}
pk: userId, sk: PROFILE#{id: 1, username: "Bill Gates"}
pk: userId, sk: FAMILYMEMBERS#{[{id:1, name: "mom"}, {id: 2, name: "dad"}]}
```

For me, the sk should be connected to another table (but that may be what we want to avoid with nosql design).

Like:

```
pk: userId, sk: [matchingItemsWithUserId]
```

Should I store everything in one object? And what about the attributes? Should the come from a table, or inserted as a json object?

Comment: This is related to NoSQL DB design - try asking on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ please

Comment: Start by watching the basic video on how DynamoDB works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnDKD_Zv0og